# .htaccess removing www. AND redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have been trying to redirect old pages for my old site to the corresponding new ones with permanent redirect.
as well as redirecting `www.example.com`  to  `example.com`

I dont seem to able to do both on the same time

at the moment redirects works for correct links from ex `www.example.com/correctlink`  to `example.com/correctlink`
but only `example.com/Info.aspx` is redirected to `example.com/about-magento-demo-store` and NOT `www.example.com/Info.aspx`

*Update

I want to remove www. AND redirect 40-50 specific adress to new specific adresses. My problem is that the redirect only works if google has saved the old link without Www. IF google has stored a link including www. then my redirect Redirect permanent example.com/tabid/61/CategoryID/13/ProductID/64/Default.aspx /index.php/solpaneler/re does not function –
*Update

my htaccess looks a bit like this
(with a few lines in the end that where present before I started editing)
(i also tried to ad a line `Redirect permanent http://www.example.com/Info.aspx http://example.com/about-magento-demo-store`   but it does not function)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.se/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
Redirect permanent /Info.aspx /about-magento-demo-store
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use rewrite rules for everything. Rewrite rules and `Redirect` don't always mix well.

```
RewriteRule ^Info\.aspx$ /about-magento-demo-store [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Great!   But I have a static list with specific links that I want redirected to specific pages.   Is it possible to make a lot of rewriterules with just static links?

Comment: You could do that. You need a lot of rewriterules before apache will get performance issues. So just keep it simple for yourself.

Comment: like below?

RewriteCond http://ww.example.com/ProductID/64/Default.aspx                
rewriteRule http://example.com/index.php/solpaneler/default.html                  
RewriteCond http://ww.example.com/ProductID/65/Default.aspx              
rewriteRule http://example.com/index.php/solpaneler2/default.html         
.............and continuing like this for about 50 links .....

Feels very strange with static variables!?

Comment: Please take another look at my code. You don't need the rewritecondition, and rewrite rule should not contain the domainname and leading slash. 50 links should be fine. I would personally be fine with using RewriteRules for 50 links. Or I would use some custom 404 page with a little php to catch these urls. Just pick the method that gets the job done the easiest.

Comment: and I still have problems with pages beginning with www. where I want www. to be removed by this   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Comment: and a custom 404 does not solve my problem  since google as saved links which i want to redirect to the new pages not a 404 page

Comment: sorry my text got a bit mixed up now - actually your rewrite code is brilliant ...still only got the problem with someone entering www. though

Comment: Your first code forces the www version, but your code in the comments forces no www. Which one do you want. Also the no-www code only works for https, so if the old urls are http it won't work.

Comment: ok thanks I didnt understand that.  I have always wanted to remove www. from all kinds of links  redirecting to the same link but without the www.                as long as I am able to keep my 50 or so static redirects as well

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem a looooooooong time ago. Here's a sample of my rewriterules:

```
# If domain name doesn't end with .com redirect to .com:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)\.(fr|net|org|eu) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1.com$1 [R=301,L]

# If domain name without "www", add them:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomainname\.(fr|com|net|org|eu) [NC]
# Ca signifie forcément que c'est sans www => forcer redirection :
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomainname.%1$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

**NB: Put this on the top of your rewrite rules, because it should be processed before anything else so that you are sure your domain name always begin with "www"**

Note that it redirects `mydomainname` only if it's "empty" i.e. nothing behind. It won't touch URLs like `http://abc.mydomainname.com` and it won't touch URLs like `http://abc.def.mydomainname.com`

Tell me if it works.

Comment: That is a beautiful script but it does not solve my problem.    I want to remove www.   AND redirect 40-50 specific adress to new specific adresses.  My problem is that the redirect only works if google has saved the old link without Www.   IF google has stored a link including www. then my redirect Redirect permanent http://www.example.com/tabid/61/CategoryID/13/ProductID/64/Default.aspx /index.php/solpaneler/re      does not function

Comment: :-)  I thought that it was that I asked in the question :-)  But ok I will try and make it clearer